# Ubuntu Boot Stuck

Tags: boot-repair

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.4, login screen is not visible got stuck here with no idea about this.
[Screen of mine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56Oxe.jpg)

Could anyone help to start my laptop in usual login screen

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 is no longer supported. I'd recommend an upgrade.

Comment: DankyNanky, No options other than upgrading

Comment: Not stating "you have to do this", but due to the age of the OS you're running, it'd probably save you alot of time.